# Undefined local variable or method 'current_user' (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, helper

I am testing my project, it is about application_helper.rb that contain this method :

```
def delete_link table=""
        if current_user.role.name=="Admin" || current_user.role.name=="Pemilik"
            link_to 'Hapus', table, :confirm => 'Anda yakin?', :method => :delete
        end
    end
```

I want to testing that method, so I make this testing on my customers_controller_test.rb like this

```
require 'test_helper'

class CustomersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  include ApplicationHelper
  setup do
    @permission = Permission.create(:name=>"Customer")
    @role = Role.create(:name=>"Admin")
    @user = User.create(:name=>"Admin", :role_id => 1, :email => "email@email.email", :password => "123456")
    @role_permission = RolePermission.create(:role_id=>@role.id, :permission_id=>@permission.id, :access=>2)
    @customer = FactoryGirl.create(:customer)

    sign_in @user    
  end

  test "should link to delete" do
    puts assert sign_in @user
    current_user = @user
    puts current_user.name
    puts current_user.role.name
    assert delete_link(customer_path(@customer.id))
    puts "2"
  end
end
```

But I got Undefined local variable or method 'current_user'. Any idea? Thx for ur advice :)

Answer (score 4):

The `current_user` method of devise is defined on the application controller and as such is not available in helpers. Supply the user via a parameter of th helper method and you are set.

Comment: But I set it into application_helper.rb, it is working for others but not working for my testing. my testing can not give parameter current user to application_helper.rb

Comment: I can't tell you how long I've been looking for this answer- thanks!